# VmWare is vSphere correct for what we want to achieve?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

We have two physical servers that we want to turn in to virtual hosts. I've been looking at the VMware vSphere 5 Essentials Kit for 3 hosts (Max 2 processors per host) and 192 GB vRAM entitlement + Subscription for 1 year for around $500. This I think seems best for what we want;

- Two physical servers
- Two VMs on each server (windows server 2008 r2 64)
- To be able to take a backup of the entire virtual server to boot elsewhere if the hardware dies for some reason - hopefully can automate the backups?

Is this the correct version of vmware to run? The choice is pretty overwhelming to say the least!

Tom

Comment: So you are going to run a total of 4 vm's, do you expect much growth? Is all the storage going to be local?  Also this is not a production enviro correct?

Comment: 4 VMs yeah, it's for our office so all local. Not much growth to be honest at the moment

Comment: why pay for vmware both xen and hyper-v will do the job quite nicely and for free.

Comment: also if you are just looking for portability for DR purposes just use native vhd boot to cover your basis.

Comment: It scares the powers that be i'm afraid. I'm a KVM fan of virtulisation but they want VMWare. I think they like the fact if box a goes bang, box b can run windows xp with vmplayer and run the vm that went bang

Comment: Will your xp workstation have enough horse power to even start the w2k8r2 servers? Native vhd boot is completely portable between most modern motherboards/devices, never had it fail even with old hp g1/g2's. The backup solutions are the same that you'd use with a normal server without suspending a vm etc ... So if you just want a decent DR solution without buying the hypervisor layer then I'd go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very close. The Essentials kit provides everything except for a means of full VM backup. vSphere Data Recovery is available in the Essentials Plus kit, which is roughly 8x the cost of the lower-end Essentials kit. Since you're not looking at shared storage and would not be able to leverage some of the higher-end features of the Essentials Plus kit, I'd go with the $500 kit you've selected and look into third-party VM-based backup solutions...

Comment: Thanks for that. If I suspend the VM, can I just take a copy of the VM as a backup?

Comment: It's more involved than that. You need a backup target and a way of managing jobs, etc. There are numerous products available that can accomplish this, though.

Comment: Do you know of any open source ones?

Comment: It's not more involved than that. If he stops the VM, he can just `scp` the files elsewhere.

Comment: @adaptr -sure, if he always wants to do his backups manually. He did ask for automating the backups. He can script all of it himself, including notifications and error-catching, or he can find/purchase a product that will do that for him.

Comment: Are there methods out there that don't need the server to be stopped? (well migrated?)

Comment: VM Explorer can make hot copies/backups of running virtual machines. The free version allows you to do this manually, the paid version allows you to schedule it. http://www.trilead.com/Buy/?c=USD